# Not able to change menu text in android

Tags: android, android-layout, menu

So im having a problem chaning the title in my menu on android. What I tried to do was create an "if" that would get the text "Home" and change it to "asdas" but for some reason it does not enter the "if". I think its easy to solve but i must be missing something.

Thanks to all

[Image of the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeDWs.png**)

```
if(menu.getHeaderType() == HeaderType.HeaderType_CATEGORY) {
                frameCategory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Spanned title = Html.fromHtml(MainActivity.this.getResources().getString(menu.getMenuResTitle()));
                TextView tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

                //This is the if that should change home to asdas
                if (tvTitle.getText() == "Home"){
                    tvTitle.setText("asdas");
                    Log.v("myApp", "ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA" );

                }else {

                    tvTitle.setText(title);

                }
                ImageView imgViewIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgViewIcon);
                imgViewIcon.setImageResource(menu.getMenuResIconSelected());
            }
```

Comment: Does the app crash?

Comment: No it does not, just does not change the text

Answer (score 0):

This is where its wrong:

```
if (tvTitle.getText() == "HOME")
//----------^^^^^^^^^------------
{
    tvTitle.setText("asdas");

    Log.v("myApp", "ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA" );

 }
```

This is how it **should be**:

```
if (tvTitle.getText().toString() == "HOME")
//-------------------^^^^^^^^^^^-----------
{
    tvTitle.setText("asdas");
    Log.v("myApp", "ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA - ASDA" );

}
```

Comment: Did not work, same thing, did not enter the "if" but thanks for trying